# Why can I convert to an int safely but not cast to an int?

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, int

Why does this work:

```
ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
int validSelection = Convert.ToInt32(cb.Tag);
if (cb.SelectedIndex != validSelection) {
    cb.SelectedIndex = validSelection;
}
```

...but this:

```
ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
int validSelection = (int)cb.Tag; // <-- fails
if (cb.SelectedIndex != validSelection) {
    cb.SelectedIndex = validSelection;
}
```

...errors out with "Object not set to a reference of an object"?

Comment: What is actually the type of the Tag?

Comment: @AndreiSchneider [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: What are you setting `Tag` to?

Comment: Tag is Object. Is sender actually a ComboBox?

Comment: Yes, sender is ComboBox. I'm assigning their SelectedIndex to their own Tag property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because [a conversion is not the same thing as a cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

`cb.Tag` is probably a `string`, not an `int`, and one is not directly convertible to the other. `Convert.ToInt32()` actually parses the `string` and creates a new `int` with the converted value.

Casts only try to interpret an instance of a type as an instance of another type.

Comment: Actually, cb.Tag is declared as `object` (but it's probably a string in the OP's case)

Comment: SelectedIndex looks like an int to me, but maybe it's not:  comboBoxPlatypusID.Tag = comboBoxPlatypusID.SelectedIndex;

Comment: @Clay, now I'm confused, why would you store `SelectedIndex` into `Tag` since it's readily available in... well, `SelectedIndex` itself?

Comment: @Frederic: I'm using it to set a combobox's selectedindex back to its original selectedindex if the user tries to change it while the form is in "readonly state." When the selectedindex is set, I set the Tag value to that same value. This is for when the form is in a "read only" state - just looking at existing values from the database. Since the same form also functions as an editable form at times, it is then set to a different state...well, you probably get the picture.

Comment: @Clay, yup, I think it's clearer now. I'd suggest you look for code paths that do not set `Tag` to `SelectedIndex`, but still exercise the code in your question afterwards. In that case, you would be casting `null` to `int` (`Tag` being an `object` defaulting to `null` if left unassigned), which would explain the `NullReferenceException`, as others have explained in their answers.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than this.  The C# cast operator performs conversions, too.  The fact that `(string)42` and `(int)"42"` are illegal is more of a design decision than an intrinsic property of the cast syntax.

Answer (score 7):

1) `Convert.ToInt32(null)` always returns 0, as said [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys)

2) You cannot cast a `null` to a `int`, as `int` represents a number. Nullable int (`int?`) allow null values.

Answer (score 4):

Boxed value types can only be unboxed to their actual type, so if the value of `Tag` is not actually an int, the cast from `object` fails. Furthermore, if the value of `Tag` is null, the cast fails because a value type can't be null.

On the other hand, when you use `Convert.ToInt32`, the method takes whatever steps are necessary to convert the value to `Int32`:

- if it's a string, parse it;
- if it's an `Int64`, unbox it to Int64, then convert it to `Int32`;
- if it's null, return 0
- etc

Answer (score 3):

The former requires that `Tag` have an `IConvertable` that supports to `ToInt32` method. The latter requires that `Tag` be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert has a number of overloads that allow it to attempt the conversion from a wide range of data types, e.g.  [Convert.ToInt32(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Your tag is presumably of a type (e.g. string) that Convert can handle.

Answer (score 1):

A cast says: "Interpret the bits in memory that represent this thing as a [whatever] (`int` in this case.)

A conversion says: "Look, this thing is actually something very different in memory, but you know how to turn it into what I want, so please do so and return the result".

Comment: And the syntax `(typename)value` performs both casts and conversions.